# How can I use sed to replace a specific pattern and add exceptions in the same line?

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, replace

I am using sed to look for and replace a pattern.

My pattern is "-"

I have the following data

```
>1-2-3-4-5 29238232382083e-9  
>1-2-3-4-5    29238232382083e-9   
>1-2-3-4-5    29238232382083e-9   
>1-2-3-4-5    29238232382083e-9
```

I want to replace the "-" in 1-2-3-4-5 by an "*" so I can get 1*2*3*4*5

However, when I do the replacement with
    sed -i -e '/-/*/g

all of the "-" are affected even the 29238232382083e-9 that turn out to 29238232382083e*9.

What could I do to replace all the "-", excepting the "-" that are located after "e" like in this case 29238232382083e-9 ?

Comment: Is your real data actually different ? If so how do you know which dashes have to be replaced ? The first four ? All but the last one ?

Comment: yeah, you need to give more detail on input... if you treat space as delimiter and want to replace `-` only in first column, awk would be better choice.. `awk '{gsub("-","*",$1); print}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/\([^e]\)-/\1*/g' /path/to/input
```

To elaborate on the `sed` statement:

- `\([^e]\)-` Here we use a grouping to look for any character other than an `e` followed by a hyphen
- `\1*` - Here we replace what was found with whatever was in that grouping (i. g. the non-e that preceded the hyphen), followed by the asterisk that is replacing that hyphen.

Note that this will not work on hyphens that are the first character of a line; for that we'll have to add a special case:

```
sed 's/\([^e]\)-/\1*/g;s/^-/*/' /path/to/input
```

This is similar, but replaces a hyphen that is the first character of the line with an asterisk.  Since it's the first character, it cannot be preceded by an `e`.

Answer (score 1):

Choose one:

***awk*** approach:

```
awk '{ gsub("-","*",$1) }1' OFS='\t' file
```

- `gsub("-","*",$1)` - replace all `-` with `*` within the 1st field

---

***perl*** approach:

```
perl -lae '$,="\t"; $F[0] =~ y/-/*/; print @F' file
```

- `-a` - auto-split `$_` into the array `@F`
- `$,="\t"` - join fields with `\t` (tab)
- `$F[0] =~ y/-/*/` - translate all `-` to `*` within the 1st field `$F[0]`

The output (for both *awk* and *perl* approaches):

```
>1*2*3*4*5  29238232382083e-9
>1*2*3*4*5  29238232382083e-9
>1*2*3*4*5  29238232382083e-9
>1*2*3*4*5  29238232382083e-9
```

---

***sed*** approach:

```
sed 'h; s/ .*$//; y/-/*/;G; s/\n[^[:space:]]*//' file
```

The output (for *sed* approach):

```
>1*2*3*4*5 29238232382083e-9  
>1*2*3*4*5    29238232382083e-9   
>1*2*3*4*5    29238232382083e-9   
>1*2*3*4*5    29238232382083e-9
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it can be done with POSIX sed, but here it's shown using GNU sed owing to simple expressions:

```
sed -e '
   s/\S\s/&\n/;:a
   s/-\(.*\)/*\1/;ta
   s/\n//
' yourfile
```

---

### Results

```
>1*2*3*4*5 29238232382083e*9
>1*2*3*4*5    29238232382083e*9
>1*2*3*4*5    29238232382083e*9
>1*2*3*4*5    29238232382083e*9
```

---

### Explanation

- Mark the boundary where we want the changes to happen.
- Then we setup a loop and perform the change in it progressively.